# python program for a book issuing process

Tags: python

For a library book issuing process i consider the following info
Information about books
Line format: Accession Number~Title

Information about borrowers
Line format: Username~Full Name

Information about checkouts
Line format: Username~Accession Number~Due Date

I am trying to write a Python program to read the data as described above and print out details about books that have been checked out. Each line should describe to one currently issued book in the following format:

**Due Date~Full Name~Accession Number~Title**
*The output should be sorted in increasing order of due date. For books due on the same date, sort in increasing order of full name.*

Here is a sample input and its corresponding output.
**Sample Input**

Books
APM-001~Advanced Potion-Making
GWG-001~Gadding With Ghouls
APM-002~Advanced Potion-Making
DMT-001~Defensive Magical Theory
DMT-003~Defensive Magical Theory
GWG-002~Gadding With Ghouls
DMT-002~Defensive Magical Theory
Borrowers
SLY2301~Hannah Abbott
SLY2302~Euan Abercrombie
SLY2303~Stewart Ackerley
SLY2304~Bertram Aubrey
SLY2305~Avery
SLY2306~Malcolm Baddock
SLY2307~Marcus Belby
SLY2308~Katie Bell
SLY2309~Sirius Orion Black
Checkouts
SLY2304~DMT-002~2019-03-27
SLY2301~GWG-001~2019-03-27
SLY2308~APM-002~2019-03-14
SLY2303~DMT-001~2019-04-03
SLY2301~GWG-002~2019-04-03
EndOfInput

**Sample Output**

2019-03-14~Katie Bell~APM-002~Advanced Potion-Making
2019-03-27~Bertram Aubrey~DMT-002~Defensive Magical Theory
2019-03-27~Hannah Abbott~GWG-001~Gadding With Ghouls
2019-04-03~Hannah Abbott~GWG-002~Gadding With Ghouls
2019-04-03~Stewart Ackerley~DMT-001~Defensive Magical Theory

```
def inp_borrower(l):
x=input()
while x!='Checkouts':
    x=x.split('~')
    x.append(0)    
    l.append(x)
    x=input()

def inp_books(checkout):
x=input()
while x!='EndOfInput':
    x=x.split('~')
    x=x[len(x)-2:]
    grade.append(x)
    x=input()
def checkout(x):
if x=='EndOfInput':
    return map(lambda x:x[1], sorted(map(lambda a:[map(int,a.split('-')),a], timestamps)))
def cal():
global li,grade
for i in li:   # i is a list containg the name and roll of a student
    j=0
    sum=0
    while j<len(grade):
        if i[0]==grade[j][0] :     # if the roll matchs
            sum=sum+com(grade[j][1])
            grade.pop(j)
            i[2]+=1
        else :
            j+=1
    if sum!=0 :
        i[2]=round(sum/i[2],2)
    print(i[0]+'~'+i[1]+'~',i[2],sep='')
li=[]             
grade=[]
x=input()
while x!='borrower':          
x=input()
stu_input(li)
li.sort()
inp_grade(grade)
cal()
```

I'd appreciate any help and advice! Please take into consideration I am really new to this stuff. I'm also not quite sure on having a function inside of a function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
def borrowers_input(b):
   x=input()
    while x!='Checkouts':
        x=x.split('~')
        b.append(x)
        x=input()

def checkouts_input(c):
    x=input()
    while x!='EndOfInput':
        x=x.split('~')
        c.append(x)
        x=input()

def output():
    global books,borrower,checkout
    date=[]
    uname=[]
    name=[]
    Anum=[]
    title=[]
    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
    date.append(checkout[i][2])

for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
    uname.append(checkout[i][0])

for i in range(0,len(uname)):
    for j in range(0,len(borrower)):
        if(uname[i] == borrower[j][0]):
            name.append(borrower[j][1])

for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
    Anum.append(checkout[i][1])

for i in range(0,len(Anum)):
    for j in range(0,len(books)):
        if(Anum[i] == books[j][0]):
            title.append(books[j][1])

final=[]
for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
    final.append(date[i]+'~'+name[i]+'~'+Anum[i]+'~'+title[i])
final.sort()
for i in range(0,len(final)):
    print(final[i])


books=[]
borrower=[]
checkout=[]
x=input()
x=input()
while x!='Borrowers':
    x=x.split('~')
    books.append(x)
    x=input()
borrowers_input(borrower)
borrower.sort()
checkouts_input(checkout)
output()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def borrowers_input(b):
   x=input()
   while x!='Checkouts':
        x=x.split('~')
        b.append(x)
        x=input()

def checkouts_input(c):
    x=input()
    while x!='EndOfInput':
        x=x.split('~')
        c.append(x)
        x=input()

def output():
    global books,borrower,checkout
    date=[]
    uname=[]
    name=[]
    Anum=[]
    title=[]
    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        date.append(checkout[i][2])

    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        uname.append(checkout[i][0])

    for i in range(0,len(uname)):
        for j in range(0,len(borrower)):
            if(uname[i] == borrower[j][0]):
                name.append(borrower[j][1])

    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        Anum.append(checkout[i][1])

    for i in range(0,len(Anum)):
        for j in range(0,len(books)):
            if(Anum[i] == books[j][0]):
                title.append(books[j][1])

    final=[]
    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        final.append(date[i]+'~'+name[i]+'~'+Anum[i]+'~'+title[i])
    final.sort()
    for i in range(0,len(final)):
        print(final[i])


books=[]
borrower=[]
checkout=[]
x=input()
x=input()
while x!='Borrowers':
    x=x.split('~')
    books.append(x)
    x=input()
borrowers_input(borrower)
borrower.sort()
checkouts_input(checkout)
output()
```